# Find "Main Object" a.k.a. contextFor when using default applyBindings

Tags: knockout.js

I try to get get the bound view model in cases when I'm applying bindings to no specific DOM element. I don't want to use either a variable to save my VM, nor a DOM-specific binding.

So if I don't use a variable to store my VM, nor use a specific DOM node as binding context, how can I get the object?

Here's what I've tried:

```
ko.applyBindings(new PageViewMode());

// ... some code ...

var vm = ko.contextFor(document); // this is what I want. I guessed it would bee bound to document or body element, but not!!

vm.load(); // this cannot be done because there is no load method on "undefined" vm
```

With variable it works like a charm:

```
var vm = new PageViewMode();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// ... some code ...

vm.load(); // OK with variable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `ko.applyBindings` without an argument then the View Model is bound to the `body` tag.

[Repro](http://jsfiddle.net/CcQgH/):

```
ko.applyBindings({});
console.log(ko.contextFor(document.body));
```

Saving a reference to your view model variable and passing it around functions and scoping it in a certain closure is probably better though.

PS. Knockout is open source, so you can [verify this in the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L434). A short quote:

```
ko.applyBindings = function (viewModelOrBindingContext, rootNode) {
    // If jQuery is loaded after Knockout, we won't initially have access to it. So save it here.
    if (!jQueryInstance && window['jQuery']) {
        jQueryInstance = window['jQuery'];
    }

    if (rootNode && (rootNode.nodeType !== 1) && (rootNode.nodeType !== 8))
        throw new Error("ko.applyBindings: first parameter should be your view model; second parameter should be a DOM node");
    rootNode = rootNode || window.document.body; // Make "rootNode" parameter optional

    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal(getBindingContext(viewModelOrBindingContext), rootNode, true);
};
```

Comment: i tried `ko.contextFor($('body').get()[0])` but not worked.  `var vm = ko.contextFor(document.body);vm.$root.load()` seems worked. Thank you

Comment: Strange. In my fiddle `$('body').get()[0]` does [seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/CcQgH/1/). In any case, glad my solution works for you.